# Arrange SQL output in Reference, Action and Date sequence (based on date of first record in the Reference Group)

Tags: sql, db2

This has been puzzling me for a while. I feel it should be possible (and fairly easy) but I can't seem to get my head around how to do it..!

Basically (in English) I want to return all the actions for today, grouping by DOC_TRACKING_ID (ie. all the same reference number to
be grouped together) and in action sequence (using sortseq) within date (of the first action for that reference group - ACTION_DTM) sequence. The data is all within one table.

I hope that makes sense..

So, what I get at the moment..

```
ACTION   ACTION_DTM             DOC_NAME                             DOC_TRACKING_ID           sortseq
FS_READ  2020-08-24 13:35:40    INVOIC_23846227.imp                  808331174204615cenode1    1
ARC_PRE  2020-08-24 13:35:40    INVOICE_20200824134740_8598875.imp   808331174204615cenode1    2
TRANSL   2020-08-24 13:35:41    -                                    808331174204615cenode1    3
ARC_POST 2020-08-24 13:35:41    INVOICE_20200824134740_8598875.edi   808331174204615cenode1    4
FTP_UP   2020-08-24 13:40:38    INVOICE_202008241347408598875.edi    808331174204615cenode1    5

FS_READ  2020-08-24 12:32:44    ORDERS_20180419-161546-373.edi       8634751742006e629node1    1
ARC_PRE  2020-08-24 12:32:46    ORDERS_20200824123245_8598307.xml    8634751742006e629node1    2
TRANSL   2020-08-24 12:32:46    -                                    8634751742006e629node1    3
ARC_POST 2020-08-24 12:32:46    ORDERS_20200824123245_8598307.ixml   8634751742006e629node1    4
FTP_UP   2020-08-24 12:38:38    ORDERS_202008241232458598307.xml     8634751742006e629node1    5
```

What I want to get..

```
ACTION   ACTION_DTM             DOC_NAME                              DOC_TRACKING_ID           sortseq
FS_READ  2020-08-24 12:32:44    ORDERS_20180419-161546-373.edi        8634751742006e629node1    1
ARC_PRE  2020-08-24 12:32:46    ORDERS_20200824123245_8598307.xml     8634751742006e629node1    2
TRANSL   2020-08-24 12:32:46    -                                     8634751742006e629node1    3
ARC_POST 2020-08-24 12:32:46    ORDERS_20200824123245_8598307.ixml    8634751742006e629node1    4
FTP_UP   2020-08-24 12:38:38    ORDERS_202008241232458598307.xml      8634751742006e629node1    5

FS_READ  2020-08-24 13:35:40    INVOIC_23846227.imp                   808331174204615cenode1    1
ARC_PRE  2020-08-24 13:35:40    INVOICE_20200824134740_8598875.imp    808331174204615cenode1    2
TRANSL   2020-08-24 13:35:41    -                                     808331174204615cenode1    3
ARC_POST 2020-08-24 13:35:41    INVOICE_20200824134740_8598875.edi    808331174204615cenode1    4
FTP_UP   2020-08-24 13:40:38    INVOICE_202008241347408598875.edi     808331174204615cenode1    5
```

I have added a blank line in both outputs just to make it easier to see the grouping. I don't need this in the output..

SQL so far..

```
select ta.ACTION, ta.ACTION_DTM, ta.DOC_NAME, DOC_TRACKING_ID,
  case 
      when ta.ACTION = 'FTP_DL'   then '1'
      when ta.ACTION = 'ARC_PRE'  then '2'
      when ta.ACTION = 'TRANSL'   then '3'
      when ta.ACTION = 'ARC_POST' then '4'
      when ta.ACTION = 'FTP_UP'   then '5'
      when ta.ACTION = 'FAIL'     then '3'
      when ta.ACTION = 'FS_READ'  then '1'
      when ta.ACTION = 'FS_WRITE' then '5'
  end as sortseq
 from DOC_TRACKING_ACTION ta
where ta.DOC_TRACKING_ID in (select distinct ta1.DOC_TRACKING_ID
                               from DOC_TRACKING_ACTION ta1
                              where ta1.ACTION_DTM >= CURRENT DATE - 0 DAYS)
order by ta.DOC_TRACKING_ID asc,
         sortseq;
```

Any help would be appreciated..! (and of course any improvements to the code is always appreciated..!)

Comment: `order by (select min(ACTION_DTM) from DOC_TRACKING_ACTION ta2 where ta2.DOC_TRACKING_ID = ta.DOC_TRACKING_ID), sortsec`

Comment: @jarlh - I thought it would be something like that as well but I get this error..  "DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=TA.DOC_TRACKING_ID, DRIVER=4.19.66 [SQL State=42703, DB Errorcode=-206] 
Next: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-206;42703;TA.DOC_TRACKING_ID, DRIVER=4.19.66 [SQL State=56098, DB Errorcode=-727]
1 statement failed."

Comment: Hmmm...don't you want descending order: `order by ta.DOC_TRACKING_ID desc, ...`?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't rely on the Tracking ID being in sequence. I don't know how the system creates this number but I know we can only rely on it to group the entries. I've only put the sorting by this field in as a starting point..